# Naming convention for main arguments

Tags: coding-standards

I recently started using arguments in my main program (here written in `C++` but could be any programming language)

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main(int argn, char* argv[]) {
    // do stuff depending on argv[1], argv[2], etc.
}
```

For now I am using mostly random naming conventions like `-t` for testing, `-d` for debugging, `-l` for printing logs e.g. There is no need for adding `-`, it is just that most shell parameters are named that way. I also use `--` for second parameters.

Is there any established naming conventions for main arguments ?

Comment: I think this will be a platform dependent answer. For instance windows seems to use a lot of things like /T /D /L where *nix systems are more apt to use -t -T -d -D

Comment: I note you use `argn` whereas the language definition is `argc` (for reasons best known to Mssrs K&R)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Gnu Standards](http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Command_002dLine-Interfaces.html)  and [GNU long argument names](http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Option-Table.html#Option-Table)

[Microsoft's suggestions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156811.aspx)